# Make Session variable available only till next request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's a scenario. A web surfer (visitor) is in the purchase page of a website. In that page, the visitor can either enter new user registration details, credit card info and complete the purchase, while creating a new user at the same time or he can sign in with his existing account. If the visitor decides to sign in using his existing account, he needs to be redirected to the same purchase page after creating a new session. I was able to achieve that by using two session variables **session[:pchase_page_after_login] = true** and **session[:path_purchase_page] = path_of_current_page**. After login, I make these varialbes nil.
All of these work fine if the user signs in from the purchase page. However, if the user goes to other pages from the purchase page, these two session variables are still stored in session and are not nil. Hence, if after broswing few other pages, the visitor tries to login, he will be redirected to the same purchase page as **session[:pchase_page_after_login] = true** and **session[:path_purchase_page] =** still exists. Thus, I would like to know if there is a way to allow a particular session variable to be available only within the next request. I know content in **:flash** is available in only within next request, but i don't know if it's wise to use for this purpose. Session variable is more suitable, but I want these two session variables to be availables only to the next request. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would recommend is that you use a before filter to achieve this. For example, you could do the following:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :delete_session_purchase

  protected

  def delete_session_purchase
    session.delete :path_purchase_page
    session.delete :purchase_page_after_login
  end
end

class SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :delete_session_purchase, :only => [:new, :create]
end
```

This would mean that on any regular request you would remove the session variables that redirect the user to the purchase page, but on the login actions you keep these variables around. This would ensure that under normal circumstances the session variables are simply deleted, except when you want to keep them around.

Comment: Thanks, your code works like a charm. I understood most part of it, would you care to explain, what :only in skip_before_filter does, and how this whole thing works?

Comment: Yeah, the only part says that you should only skip the before filter (delete_session_purchase function) when the new or create actions are called on the sessions controller. When the actual before filter does run, it simply deletes session[:path_purchase_page] and session[:purchase_page_after_login] ensuring that under normal circumstances the redirect won't happen.

Comment: OK, I understand how this works. The deletion of these two session variables does not occur in the new and create action of the sessioncontroller. And the session variable remains undeleted even if i send the "sign in" request a couple of times, but this does not matter, as the user is already in the sign in page. This is beautiful logic. Thanks.

Comment: If those are the only items are if you want all the items stored in the session to be cleared, you can use request.reset_session to clear them all at once instead.

Comment: @Sam, the problem with resetting the session at this time is that the user would never be able to be logged in, and any other useful session information would be removed. I think it's best to simply remove the two session variables since this results in the least number of side effects.

Comment: Ya, clearing all session variables might not be a good idea, as i am using some plugins and i don't want to be inadvertently messing up any session variables they might have been using

Answer (score 1):

You do want the `flash` in this case. It's stored in the session, but it's just automatically nilled after the next request. A custom solution will end up effectively replicating what the flash already does.

Alternately, you could just `redirect_to :back` after login, which would take them back to the page that they logged in from.